# How to run windows update after creation of azure virtual machine via powershell?

Tags: windows, powershell, azure

I have a script I run in the azure powershell to create a virtual machine. After it is created I remote in and run windows update then install our app. Looking at maybe automating the whole thing.

Once I provision the vm with `New-AzureVM` I see I can use the `WaitForBoot` command to wait for it to start up but then how do I run remote commands on the vm? For example to start a windows update, transfer and run my app installation files?

I saw a [blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/09/07/weekend-scripter-remoting-the-cloud-with-windows-azure-and-powershell/) about this from a couple of years back where he decribes using `Invoke-Command` but it is not simple, involves downloading a certificate, installing it to your computer as an administrator, etc. Is there a simpler way? If I do it as he describes will I be able to run windows update and install my app? Is powershell the right tool for this task?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned already the [Remote PowerShell option](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Configures-Secure-Remote-b137f2fe), which should still be a valid option.

Another way to tweak an Azure VM is by creating a custom PowerShell script, put it on Azure Blob Storage to have it at a central location and then use the [Custom Script Extension](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/virtual-machines-extensions-customscript/) to run it within the VMs.